# response redirect with '+'

Tags: c#, asp.net, response

when I write

```
Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx?Name=" + TextBox1.Text);
```

then

```
string input = Request.QueryString["Name"];
```

if I write yahoo+music in textbox

the input will be yahoo music why ? and how can I keep the '+' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plus in the URL means a space. You should URL encode the value that you put in the URL:

```
Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx?Name=" + Server.UrlEncode(TextBox1.Text));
```

Answer (score 7):

`+` is the encoding for space in query strings. To encode `+` you need to use `%2b`.

Try [`UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) which should handle this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've another way - although a little bit 'tricky' - to reach your goal by passing '+'(or any other special character) in query string

when you pass the query string you write like this:

Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?Name="+TextBox1.Text.Replace("+","_"));

then it will pass Default.aspx?Name=Yahoo_Music

and to request it, just replace again

string input = Request.QueryString["Name"].Replace("_","+");

input will be: Yahoo+Music.

although this way a little bit tricky but sometimes this way very helpful to pass special character in query string.

Thanks